# Dart remove first comma from string if exists

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a string of numbers separated by commas. I would like to remove the first and last comma if it exists.

```
//qlist = ',6063,6077,6051,5925,6069,6054,6071,6049,5903,5858,5760,';
if (qlist.substring(qlist.length - 1) == ','){
      qlist= qlist.substring(0,qlist.length - 1);
    }
    if (qlist.substring(0) == ','){
      qlist= qlist.substring(1,qlist.length);
    }
```

Please suggest the right approach.

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following:

```
int startSlice = 0;
int endSlice = myString.length;    

if (myString.startsWith(‘,’)) 
 startSlice = 1;
if (myString.endsWith(‘,’))
 endSlice -= 1;

myString = myString.subString(startSlice, endSlice);
```